# sequelize model methods "this" issue

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

i am having issue to user JWT with sequelize, cuz i need to create a model method and then apply this model method whenever i want to perform a validation.

the problem is that when I try to use "this" the return is "user".

can someone give me an explanation about why and some possible workaround? ty.

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../sequelize/db')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        require: true,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            len: [4, 12]
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        require: true,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            len: {
                args: [6, 12],
                msg: 'password between 6 and 12 characters'
            },
            async set(password) {
                this.setDataValue('password', await bcrypt.hash(password, 8))
            }
        }
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        require: true,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    },
    avatar: {
        type: DataTypes.BLOB,
    },
    profile: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT
    }
})

User.genAuthToken = async function () {
    const user = this
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user.id }, 'qweasd', { expiresIn: '7 days' })
    return token
}

const a = async () => {
    await User.create({
        id: 'asdd',
        name: 'nishia',
        email: 'emaia@am.me',
        password: 'asdasd'
    })
    const token = await User.genAuthToken()
}

a()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an instance method not a class (static) method:

```
User.prototype.genAuthToken = async function () {
    const user = this
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user.id }, 'qweasd', { expiresIn: '7 days' })
    return token
}
...
const a = async () => {
    const newUser = await User.create({
        id: 'asdd',
        name: 'nishia',
        email: 'emaia@am.me',
        password: 'asdasd'
    })
    const token = await newUser.genAuthToken()
}
```

Comment: big hugs for you bro. thanks for saving me. i had left this project since i couldnt figure that out. im in hard trouble learning sequelize throught documentation. this completely saved my project. thanks for providing the names so i can search for the terms!